# Positionning 3 split-buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have 3 buttons in a row (2 bootstrap split-buttons and 1 basic button) and I want to place them accordingly. So, everyone is inside a div of width: 32%; (themselves in a div of 96%, so exactly the third for each "mini-div"). Then, I want that every button gets centered in their "mini-divs". I tried to `margin: auto`, but it's not working. I made it with the basic button by using `align-text: center`. However, the 2 others, which are `split-buttons`, stick to the left side of their divs.

Here's an image (the blue boxes are the border of the "mini-divs":

[image: screencap]

Here's my HTML...

```
<div id="boutons">
    <!-- Split button, ajouter -->
    <div class="btn-group dropup" id="btn1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter 1 vecteur</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="ajouter">
            <li><a href="#">1</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Split button, enlever -->
    <div class="btn-group dropup" id="btn2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Enlever 1 vecteur</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="enlever">
            <li><a href="#">1</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="btn3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Activer le graphique</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and CSS

```
#boutons
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 96%;
}

.btn-group a
{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

#btn1, #btn2, #btn3
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
}

#btn3
{
    text-align: center;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put split button (or `btn-group`) inside another div:

```
<div id="boutons">
  <div id="btn1">
    <div class="btn-group dropup" >
      <!-- btn-group content -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="btn2">
    <div class="btn-group dropup">
      <!-- btn-group content -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="btn3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Activer le graphique</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then this css would work perfectly:

```
#boutons > div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your buttongroup buttons in an additional div to make the alignment work:
take a look here: 
http://www.bootply.com/6FnWLABceC

```
<div id="btn1">
    <div class="btn-group dropup">
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#btn3
{
    text-align: center;    
}
```

Only apply to your btn3

And

```
.btn-group a
{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Is apply to your `a` inside your btn's

Try:

```
#btn1,
#btn2,
#btn3{
    text-align: center;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS to this

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
#boutons
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 96%;
}

.btn-group a
{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

#btn1, #btn2, #btn3
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%; background:#fc0;text-align: center;
}

#btn3
{
    text-align: center;    
}
.btn-group > .btn, .btn-group-vertical > .btn{float:none;}
.btn-group > .btn + .dropdown-toggle {
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jjA7LW6G55) (I changed the bg color so you can see the alignment, but you must obviously adjust it to your needs)

Comment: yeah, seems to work on bootply but not in my browser :s

Comment: then you must have something else affecting the outcome, it's exactly the same answer you gave as valid only that fixing the issue of the dropdowns

Comment: It's ok, someone else found a way to make it work. Thanks anyway!